# Bluez GATT server (peripheral) secure characteristic read

Tags: c++, linux, bluez, gatt

I have implemented a GATT server in CPP which communicates to Bluez stack over DBUS APIs. I am able to advertise, expose characteristics and have clients connect with me. My reference is the doc and test folder in the bluez folder.

I would like to make my characteristic accessible only on secure (not legacy) pairing. 
So I have added 'secure-write' and 'secure-read' flags to my characteristic. 
When I try to read and write them using the nRF connect tool I see that bluez is not forcing for pairing requests and I am able to read/write the characteristic.

My app does not register any agent with the bluez since my peripheral has NoInputOutput capability.

```cpp
static int GetHandlerGattChar(sd_bus* bus, const char* path, const char* interface, const char* prop, sd_bus_message* reply,
                      void* userdata, sd_bus_error* error) {
.....
    if (property == "UUID") {
        ret = sd_bus_message_append(reply, "s", "12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef1");
    } else if (property == "Service") {
        ret = sd_bus_message_append(reply, "o", DBUS_OBJECT_SERVICE0_NAME.c_str());
    } else if (property == "Flags") {
        ret = sd_bus_message_append(reply, "as", 3, "write-without-response", "secure-write", "secure-read");
    } else {
        ret = sd_bus_error_set(error, SD_BUS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROPERTY, "" /* message*/);
    }
......
}
```

I don't understand what I am missing. 
Any help/support would be really appreciated.

Comment: The one which has worked for me now is encrypt-read and encrypt-write which forces a pairing.